# Outline a region in a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have two 2D numpy arrays (of the same dimensions) that I am plotting using matplotlib.  The first array I've plotted as a color map in gray-scale.  The second one represents an aperture, but it is an irregular shape (some of the pixels get outlined, and it is a set of horizontal and vertical lines that form the outline).  I am not sure how to ask it to plot this second array.  The array is composed of three numbers (0, 1, and 3), and I only need the pixels of one value (3) to be outlined, but I need the outline to encompass the region of these pixels, not the pixels individually.  I need the interior of all the pixels to remain transparent so that I can see the gray-scale color map through it.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: I just noticed that you unaccepted my answer below. There is nothing wrong with that if you have a good reason. However, just to learn more, it would be very interesting, if you commented on the reason. That way I could learn what is wrong with my answer and possibly improve it so that it answers your question better!

Comment: @DrV, There's nothing wrong with the answer, per se, but I haven't been able to reproduce your results using the code you provided.  I'm trying to determine why.  I also haven't been able to adapt your code to my purpose, so I thought that perhaps I would re-accept it as The Answer once I indeed have found it to answer my question.  I do plan on re-accepting it, though, as it was a very good answer.

Answer (score 15):

That is an interesting question, if I understood it correctly. In order to make sure what you mean, you would like to draw a line with some color around all contiguous areas where the pixel value is 3.

I do not think there is a ready-made function for that, but let's not let that stop us. We will need to create our own function.

We can start by creating a boolean map of the area which needs to be outlined:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# our image with the numbers 1-3 is in array maskimg
# create a boolean image map which has trues only where maskimg[x,y] == 3
mapimg = (maskimg == 3)

# a vertical line segment is needed, when the pixels next to each other horizontally
#   belong to diffferent groups (one is part of the mask, the other isn't)
# after this ver_seg has two arrays, one for row coordinates, the other for column coordinates 
ver_seg = np.where(mapimg[:,1:] != mapimg[:,:-1])

# the same is repeated for horizontal segments
hor_seg = np.where(mapimg[1:,:] != mapimg[:-1,:])

# if we have a horizontal segment at 7,2, it means that it must be drawn between pixels
#   (2,7) and (2,8), i.e. from (2,8)..(3,8)
# in order to draw a discountinuous line, we add Nones in between segments
l = []
for p in zip(*hor_seg):
    l.append((p[1], p[0]+1))
    l.append((p[1]+1, p[0]+1))
    l.append((np.nan,np.nan))

# and the same for vertical segments
for p in zip(*ver_seg):
    l.append((p[1]+1, p[0]))
    l.append((p[1]+1, p[0]+1))
    l.append((np.nan, np.nan))

# now we transform the list into a numpy array of Nx2 shape
segments = np.array(l)

# now we need to know something about the image which is shown
#   at this point let's assume it has extents (x0, y0)..(x1,y1) on the axis
#   drawn with origin='lower'
# with this information we can rescale our points
segments[:,0] = x0 + (x1-x0) * segments[:,0] / mapimg.shape[1]
segments[:,1] = y0 + (y1-y0) * segments[:,1] / mapimg.shape[0]

# and now there isn't anything else to do than plot it
plt.plot(segments[:,0], segments[:,1], color=(1,0,0,.5), linewidth=3)
```

Let us test this by generating some data and showing it:

```
image = np.cumsum(np.random.random((20,20))-.5, axis=1)
maskimg = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype='int')
maskimg[image > 0] = 3

x0 = -1.5
x1 =  1.5
y0 = 2.3
y1 = 3.8

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(maskimg, origin='lower', extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1], cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('tight')
```

After that we run the procedure on the top, and get:

[image]

The code can be made much denser, if needed, but now comments take a lot of space. With large images it might be wise to optimize the image segment creation by finding continuous paths. That will reduce the number of points to plot by a factor of up to three. However, doing that requires a bit different code, which is not as clear as this one. (If there will appear comments asking for that and an appropriate number of upvotes, I'll add it :)

Comment: If the mask does not contain any segments, l will be empty and it fails ;-) Thanks for the awesome snippet!

Comment: I translated it into Julia for a slightly more simple case where the segments are vertical and cannot be underneath each other. Your code is excellent to start thinking about the problem, right from the adjacency mask to interchange of rows and columns for plotting coordinates.